# Change background-image using jQuery addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change a css background using jQuery `addClass`? I am using the following code but it just stays on the initial background image.

HTML

```
<div id="background">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                for (var x = 10; x > 0; x--) {
                    $"#background").addClass(background2).delay(2000);
                    $("#background").removeClass("background2");
                    $("#background").addClass("background3").delay(2000);
                    $("#background").removeClass("background3").delay(2000);
                };
            });;
```

CSS

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-image: url(backgroundimage1.JPG);
    background-position: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}

.background1 {
    background-image: url(backgroundimage1.JPG);
}

.background2 {
    background-image: url(backgroundimage2.JPG);
}

.background3 {
    background-image: url(backgroundimage3.JPG);
}
```

Comment: Because you remove the class immediately after adding it, you won't see the effect; the browser doesn't re-paint the screen until it absolutely has to in such a case. You should probably investigate `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` if you want to cycle through backgrounds over time.

Comment: ^ that, and the `delay()` does nothing when changing classes, it's meant for animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly you're adding classes and instantly removing them as `delay` does not have an effect on the `css()` method. To achieve what you require you could use `setInterval` instead. Secondly, you need to increase the specificity of the `backgroundX` classes so they override the default styles on the `#background` element. Try this:

```
var count = 0;
var classes = [ 'background1', 'background2', 'background3' ];

function updateBackground() {
    $('#background').removeClass(classes.join(' ')).addClass(classes[count % classes.length]);
    count++;
}

setInterval(updateBackground, 2000);
```

```css
#background.background1 {
    background-image: url(backgroundimage1.JPG);
}

#background.background2 {
    background-image: url(backgroundimage2.JPG);
}

#background.background3 {
    height: 20%;
    background-image: url(backgroundimage3.JPG);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/jb9ano4o/)

Note the example is using `background-color` but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write proper CSS-rules. Now their priority doesn't let you to see the changes. Write like this

```
#background {
    background-image: url("backgroundimage1.JPG");
}

#background.background1 {
    background-image: url(backgroundimage1.JPG);
}

#background.background2 {
    background-image: url(backgroundimage2.JPG);
}

#background.background3 {
    height: 20%;
    background-image: url(backgroundimage3.JPG);
}
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at but the suggestion can be improved. Instead of even setting an image with `#background`, create one additional `.background<number>` class. That way you're not concatenating selectors and only need to use a single class to override with.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, that's because IDs always have a [higher specificity than classes](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

While you can do what the other answers suggest (#background.background1 and so on), I'd recommend using the ID only for jQuery targeting and avoid using IDs in your CSS files, since it doesn't have any advantage over using a class and it has many disadvantages (no reusability, specificity issues…). See [why you should avoid IDs in yous CSS files](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/)